# Adding Bootstrap to Jekyll

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

I'm new to Jekyll and would like to pull in some of the Twitter Bootstrap functionality. Has anyone done this and, if so, do you have any advice? I would have gone with Jekyll-Bootstrap, but there is no longer support for it. I have built my Jekyll site and am hoping there's a way to pull in Bootstrap.

Comment: Have you tried to use bootstrap with your site already?  If so can you paste an example of what's failing?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As Jekyll natively supports sass, you can use [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass).

I personally install it with the `bower install bootstrap-sass` command.

This installs Bootstrap and Jquery in the `bower_components` folder.

#### Configuration

In your _config.yml add :

```
sass:
  # loading path from site root
  # default to _sass
  sass_dir: bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets

  # style : nested (default), compact, compressed, expanded
  #         :nested, :compact, :compressed, :expanded also works
  # see http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style
  # on a typical twitter bootstrap stats are :
  # nested 138,7kB, compact 129,1kB, expanded 135,9 kB, compressed 122,4 kB
  style: compressed
```

#### Javascript

If you want to use javascript, in your _includes/footer.html add :

```
<script src="{{ site.baseurl }}/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ site.baseurl }}/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

#### Use

In `css/main.scss` delete previous content and add

```
---
# Only the main Sass file needs front matter (the dashes are enough)
---
@charset "utf-8";

/* path to glyphicons */
$icon-font-path: "/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";

/* custom variable */
$body-bg: red;

/* any style customization must be before the bootstrap import */
@import "bootstrap";
```

You can see all variables available in `bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss`

You can remove you old _sass folder.

Now your css file is generated at each build.

Comment: In case you want to leave your `sass_dir` alone (and let it default to `_sass`), you could instead make your import statement:

`@import "../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";`

Comment: From [jekyll issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3366): in your _config.yml instead of using `sass_dir`define multiple `load_paths` e.g. `- bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets` and `- _sass`. That way you are more flexible.

Comment: Works only when not in safe mode, so not on gh-pages. https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sass-converter/blob/master/lib/jekyll/converters/scss.rb#L77

Answer (score 8):

> Update for Bootstrap 4.3.1 & Jekyll 4.0

you can use bunder to install BS into your site

```
bundle install bootstrap
```

add it to gem file:

```
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.3.1'
```

get the path of BS

```
bundle info bootstrap
```

Add that path to _config.yml

```
sass:
    load_paths:
        - _sass
        -  C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootstrap-4.3.1/assets/stylesheets
```

relative path can also be added instead.

Finally, add bootstrap to `style.scss`

```
 @import "bootstrap";
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/

Comment: Great. Works fine.

Comment: I know this is old, but would you be able to expand on "relative path can also be added instead."?

Comment: How can I go with that configuration on GitHub Pages?

Comment: Is there a way to not hard-code the bundle path? I.e. not having to adapt the path when updating ruby or bootstrap?

Answer (score 5):

## Update for Bootstrap 4 Beta

[As Bootstrap 4 Beta now runs on Sass](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2017/08/10/bootstrap-4-beta/), you could use the "official" bower package.

Here's what I did:

### 1. Install Bootstrap using Bower

`bower install bootstrap#v4.0.0-beta --save` to install Bootstrap and its dependencies to the `bower_components` folder.

### 2. Configuration

In `_config.yml`, I changed the Sass folder and excluded `bower_components` from processing:

```
sass:
   sass_dir: assets/css

# Exclude from processing.
exclude:
  - bower_components
```

### 3. Sass

I changed `assets/css/main.scss` as following:

```
---
# Only the main Sass file needs front matter (the dashes are enough)
---
@charset "utf-8";


@import "variables";  // (2)
@import "../../bower_components/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"; // (1)

// Import other styling below
// ...
```

**(1)** Note that the second import statement has to be relative to the Sass directory specified in `_config.yml`. Since I choose it to be the folder that also contains the `main.scss`, the asset linking in your favourite IDE (e.g. WebStorm) won't break.

**(2)** To overwrite Bootstrap Sass variables, I created `assets/css/_variables.scss` which has to be imported before the Bootstrap library.

### 4. Javascript

Since I did not find a way to use the JS shipped into `bower_components`, I choosed to include the CDN versions [as proposed by Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach from GorvGoyl answer, could be installing gems in your project folder. In this way the dependencies are bounded with the project.

#### Prerequisites

Create new blank project:

```
foo@bar:~$ jekyll new myproject --blank
```

Move inside project folder and initialize Bundler:

```
foo@bar:~/myproject$ bundle init
```

Configure Bundler install path inside a project subdirectory:

```
foo@bar:~/myproject$ bundle config set --local path 'vendor/bundle'
```

Now gems installed with Bundler will be under `vendor/bundler` project subdirectory.

Add Jekyll to Gemfile:

```
foo@bar:~/myproject$ bundle add jekyll
```

#### Add Bootstrap to the project

Add Bootstrap to Gemfile:

```
foo@bar:~/myproject$ bundle add bootstrap
```

Get Bootstrap path:

```
foo@bar:~/myproject$ bundle info bootstrap
```

Add the relative Bootstrap path to `_config.yml`:

```yaml
sass:
  load_paths:
      - ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootstrap-5.3.1/assets/stylesheets
```

Last step, import Bootstrap inside your main `.scss` file under `asset/css` path:

```scss
---
---
@import "bootstrap";
```