# How to manage versions of Twitters Bootstrap in my local project folder?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, rubygems, dependencies, jekyll, bundler

I'm building a website with Jekyll. That website should be shipped with Twitters Bootstrap.

I was wondering if it is somehow possible to add bootstrap to my *project folder* using `gem`/`bundler`.

My alternative would be using `npm` to install `bower` and then use `bower` to install bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [jekyll-bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-bootstrap-sass) gem, but it's not used by github pages and keep sources hidden in gem directory.

I prefer to use bower ([see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28737999/1548376)). The bower way allows me to make SCSS sources available for designer without the need to search them in a gem (I personally find that "hiding" templates or styles in a gem is not easing development because it creates some bad "magic").