# Adding Bootstrap SASS to Jekyll/GitHub Pages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4, jekyll, github-pages

How can I bring Bootstrap's SASS into my Jekyll project so that it will work on GitHub pages?

This is not a duplicate of this question: [Adding Bootstrap to Jekyll](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28733425/3063273). That question has little to do with GitHub Pages, and the answers mention using Bower, which I don't think GitHub Pages supports.

This doesn't work:

```
---
---
// This is at "/assets/css/site.scss"
@import "bootstrap";
```

I get this error:

> File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap

I have tried `bundle add bootstrap` but that doesn't change anything.

I am able to `npm install bootstrap` and get Jekyll to pull in needed things from `node_modules/bootstrap` per [the instructions on this site](https://simpleit.rocks/how-to-add-bootstrap-4-to-jekyll-the-right-way/) and it works on my machine, but this isn't a suitable solution for GitHub Pages because GitHub Pages does not use `npm`.

Comment: is there any updates for this?

Comment: @chiayongkang Sorry, I don't have any updates. Unless GitHub Pages has started using `npm` or something like that then perhaps the only solution is to include `node_modules` in source control so that GitHub Pages will be able to see it. Not a very pleasant solution if you ask me :( I've kind of moved on to other projects so I haven't really investigated this since 2018

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure that your bootstrap sass file has no prepending two lines of 3 dashes, so in `bootstrap.scss` delete this.

```
---
---
```

After this open your `config.yml` file and add the following lines, my recommendation is to add a folder at root level called `scss/` with all your `scss` files (this is a little vague here, for me it worked the best because there are a variety of posts suggesting it that way since sometimes Jekyll::Converters::Scss? seems to break the relative path).

```
sass:
  sass_dir: scss
```

And you should be good to go with `@import "bootstrap.scss";` in your one of your other `scss`.
In the other files you want to compile the `.scss` to `.css` so make sure to include the two lines of 3 dashes there and add them to your `<head>` as a `.css` file.